# Overridden function not getting called in Javascript (strict mode)

Tags: javascript, function, overriding, node-modules

I am running into an issue where an overridden function is not getting invoked.

The base implementation is as below.

```
// I have a base file that defines and exports a function like this
function a() {
    // do something
}

module.exports = {
    a: a,

    b: function () {
        $('body').on('some_event', function (e, response) {
            // do something
            
            // call a
            a();
        });
    }
}
```

The override is as follows.

```
// I need to override the function a() and here is what I am doing
var base = require('mystuff/base');

function a() {
    // override implementation
}

base.a = a;

module.exports = base;
```

When `some_event` is raised on the page, `b()` executes and in the last step it is executing `a()` in the base implementation not the overridden one.

Can someone tell me how I can fix the code above to make it execute the overridden function when the event is raised? The function `b()` should execute and in its last step it should execute the overridden `a()`.

Comment: Your base file uses a reference and you never call the objects `a` but the reference to the function. You need to use a context `this` to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need just a couple of changes. I cleaned the code a bit below. The significant change is changing the reference to the call to `a()`:

NOTE: edited based upon OPs comment.

```js
class Base {
  a() {
    console.log('in mystuff/base a()');
  }
  b() {
    setTimeout(this.a, 2000);
  }
}
```

You can see this work in this repl:

https://repl.it/@randycasburn/overriding-imports

Comment: Thanks Randy. However, in my case all JS files are enforced with `strict` mode and hence `this` does not work. I just edited the posting to add that essential details. Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: I've updated the post and the repl to use class syntax.